# UI Views invisible while starting the app some times in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my main `activity` i have DrawerLayout with two `fragments` one for the `sliding drawer`, one for
the main screen, both the `fragments` have `listviews` with different data.

When I upgrade app or new install on the existing one, some times UI views invisible.In the main `listview` i am downloading some data from the server in the `background thread`.

In the Sliding `fragment`, listview is populated with static data, in the main listview data is not visible but i scroll on the empty screen mainlist data is visible, but at the same time if i click on the `listview` in `slidefragment` list goes completely invisible

Answer (score 0):

At last i found the solution on my own, Here the issues is with DrawerLayout with two fragments. some times it behaves strangely, Actually this is my Launcher activity, when i changed the Launcher Activity and starting this Activity from there fixed the issue.